# Toggle wordpress subnav sidebar items

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slidetoggle

I have a sidebar nav within a template in Wordpress. I'm using CSS to hide the subnav `<li>` elements, and using jQuery to toggle their visibility. This works outside of WP, but not within the template.

The question is how/where to embed the JS(already tried the footer/header), to make this work.

This is how its supposed to work: http://jsfiddle.net/MLUb8/

WP code:

```
<div class="l-sidebar at_left">
    <div class="l-sidebar-h i-widgets">
        <!--IF IS PAGE-->
        <?php if ( is_page() ) { ?>
            <!--SHOW ALL SUBPAGES IN UNORDERED LIST-->
            <ul><?php
                if($post->post_parent){
                    $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=1");
                }
                else{
                    $children = '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';
                    $children .= wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=1");
                }
                echo $children; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

RENDERED HTML:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-3671 page_item_has_children current_page_item">
    <a href="http://test.html">Executive Team</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="page_item page-item-3791">
            <a href="test.html">Board of Directors</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-3771">
            <a href="test.html">Management</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

jQuery from fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("ul li.page-item-3791, ul li.page-item-3771").hide();
$("li.current_page_item").click(function() {
    $('.page_item .page-item-3791, ul li.page-item-3771').slideToggle('fast');
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Considering that your code is wrapped in document.ready, it can go anywhere. Add it to a template or use a WP extension to include it.

Comment: I tried adding it to the page, but its not working for the links.

Comment: It would help if you'd show the rendered HTML. jQuery doesn't care what your PHP looks like.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#menu-item")` doesn't exist in your HTML sample. You could do:

```
$('.children').hide();

$('.page_item_has_children').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.children').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: I've changed the code a bit in the jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/MLUb8/4), and now controlling the specific nav items at specific classes. I can't seem to get the code to work within the wordpress site, but it obviously works correctly in the fiddle. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, I removed 'medium' from your code above because, near as I can tell, it does nothing. I don't think it's a valid argument (unless you've defined it somewhere), and the default is about that speed anyway.

Comment: The main point now, is where to put it in wordpress. I've tried the header.php, the actual page template its used on and the footer.php files with no success.